# Relative Pathing for Project Resources in C# and DotNetCore

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-core, wpf-controls

I have a C# project, using WPF, with dotnet core version 3.  I have added a .PNG image in visual studio 2019, with the path Images/Locations, with a build action of "Resource", and a copy to output of "Copy if Newer".

In C#, I store the relative path to this image in the ImagePath property of CurrentLocation.  In WPF, I use an image control, where the source is a binding to this ImagePath property.  You can see the relevant code at the end of this post.

My problem is that the image does not appear, but **does** appear when I change the path string in the ImagePath property to a full/disk path, e.g. C:\Users\etc, making no other changes to the underlying code, the binding in the WPF control, etc.  Further, I'm 99% certain that the syntax I'm using to get the relative path of this image is correct for dotnet framework, so I'm assuming this is a change in function made going from framework to core - unfortunately, I'm not able to find any documentation on this.  Any ideas what is going on, or how relative paths are meant to function in dotnet core?  Can they not be used?

**Relevant C# (ImagePath property is defined)**

```
CurrentLocation = new Location
{
   Description = "default location description"
  ,ImagePath   = "/simpleRPG_Engine;component/Images/Locations/tempHome.png" // broken???
  ,Name        = "default location"
  ,XCoordinate = 0
  ,YCoordinate = 0
};
```

**Relevant XAML (ImagePath property is bound)**

```
<Image      x:Name                = "worldImage"
            Grid.Row              = "1"
            Height                = "250"
            HorizontalAlignment   = "Center"
            Source                = "{Binding CurrentLocation.ImagePath}"
            VerticalAlignment     = "Center"
            Width                 = "250"

/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tempHome.png isn't included in the project. open your .net core project file in edit mode and find your resource.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\Locations\tempHome.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

if it isn't , try to write the include code. or build action set to resource -> none -> resource. and rebuild.

Comment: It appears to be included in the .csproj file, see below.

`<Resource Include="Images\Locations\tempHome.png">`

Comment: No effect on rebuild, same issue.